# Mapear tablas existentes con Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, code-first

estoy intentando crear una API en ASP.NET Core siguiendo un curso de Udemy, la cuestión es que tal curso se basa en una base de datos y unas tablas creadas mediante migraciones. Pero yo necesitaría poder mapear unas tablas ya existentes con datos. Pero por mucho que busco información, no sé si será por las versiones de EF, no encuentro nada que me funcione:
La estructura actual es la siguiente:
En el fichero Startup.cs tengo este método:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
  
}
```

En la clase contexto:

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>options)
        :base(options)

    {
       
    }
    public DbSet<Autor> Autors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Llibre> Llibres { get; set; }
}
```

Y las clases Autor:

```
namespace WebAPI.Entities
{
    public class Autor
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public List<Llibre> Llibres { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Y Libro

```
namespace WebAPI.Entities
{
    public class Llibre
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Titulo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int AutorID { get; set; }
        public Autor Autor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Iniciando una Migración EF me crea las tablas y ya puedo acceder a ellas mediante los objetos Autor y Llibre.
¿Cómo podría hacer lo mismo pero prescindiendo de las migraciones y mapeando tablas ya existentes?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: dejame ver si te entendi, quieres mapear la base de datos, y que no se pierdan los datos que hay en la bd?

Comment: Exactamente, quiero poder mapear unas tablas ya existentes para tractar con ellas en lugar de crearlas desde el codigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tienes que crear el modelo de datos con el comando :
Scaffold-DbContext tuserverSQL Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutPutDir Tucapetadondesealojaranlasrelaciones

ejemplo :
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=DESKTOP-F1AL5C9\SQLEXPRESS;database=SARSCOV2;Trusted_Connection=true;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutPutDir Models/DB

Comment: Cierto, solo añadir que para poder usar el comando Scaffold, ha de referenciarse previamente EntityFrameworkCore.Tools desde el gestor de paquetes.